# winforms in conjunction with asp net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I created a WinForms project in which the figures are drawn, the data of which is stored in the database.

After that, I created a Asp.NET Web Service project (Empty Template) and encapsulated all work with the database in WebMethods (I used the asmx file).
Then I connected this service to the Winforms project and from there I call these web methods to get data about the shapes and their further rendering.

I have the following theoretical questions:

1. Can this architecture of this design be considered client-server, that is, can the created web service be called a server?
2. Can we talk about this design as a microservice one?

Comment: Why are you creating an ASP.NET Web Service in 2021? That technology is dead. You should be using the Web API functionality inside of ASP.NET Core MVC these days.

Comment: ASMX died in 2006 when it was replaced by WCF. This isn't just a library issue - ASMX never supported SOAP 1.2 or the WS-* interoperability standards that WCF supports. There's no reason to use it. It's not supported

Comment: Careful - one of the great reasons to use asp.net + web forms is the INCREIBLE ease and lower learning curve. For anyone that comes from a desktop environment using that layout form, drag and drop and having an interactive web form to drop controls on to? It reduces learning curves by about 3x or more.

Comment: So the easy to use designers, drag + drop and interactive development that web forms gives is a HUGE bonus here. MVC does not have a interactive web forms designer. So, you now will prevent 80% or more people jumping from .net desktop tools to web land. Web forms is a technology designed to pull desktop developers into web land and development and allows them to leverage existing know how. To chase people away from this option is to chase away new asp.net developers. And then you wonder why the asp.net marketplace is waning? Careful who you case away else you be alone as a asp.net user.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, but, unfortunately, my questions have not been resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can this architecture of this design be considered client-server, that is, can the created web service be called a server?

Well, it is in fact a server. Any software that hits ANY kind of server is considered client to server. So even if you say are 100% desktop, and pull data from SQL server? In that case that is a classic client to server setup by any accepted standard.

and creating a web service (some function and methods exposed on a web page)? yes, that again is a client to server setup.

> Can we talk about this design as a microservice one?

Well, again, that's really just a plate of semantics.  A tiny one web service ? That could be certainly defined as a microservice. That term is NOT really that you called one web service, but the term tends to mean that you built up a bunch of small web services. In fact you could still call that a web API and be safe from a "definition" here.

I can't say there is a LOT that distinguishes a web services from "microservices". That term tends to just mean that there is a web site, and it has a bunch of smaller set of  methods and things that you can consume. (as opposed to say a full blown web site). Some do use the term to suggest that you consume many different services from many different sites. So you might pull weather data from one site, and say population data from another site, and then might say estimate that ice cream sales will go up based on weather and population.

So, I could accept that microservices tends to suggest that you are consuming MORE then one web sites methods and properties as compared to only consuming web methods from ONE site. So "microservices" is a term used to describe the architecture setup - NOT that you JUST deciding to call one web method on one site. So I would suggest the difference between just calling one web site method vs that of microservices? Well, I think the difference would be that you using a BUNCH of different sites, and pulling tiny bits and parts from each of those sites web methods they expose - hence "micro" or a "small" bunch of services are combined to add up to something with a larger feature set - all based on those tiny bit and parts cobbled together.

So the term "microservices" does not mean that you decided to call ONE web method, but you as a developer decided to cobble together a whole bunch of those tiny web methods into one larger result. So microservices is the MORE the result of the choices you as a developer makes as opposed to the FACT of calling one web service/method.